# jQuery - Lightbox thumbnails not working in PHP 5.3

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery lightbox in my application. My application runs on PHP 5.2 and it works fine with jQuery 1.7.2. I have included lightbox.css and the jQuery plugin.

Now, I moved this to another system with PHP 5.3 and on this system the lightbox showcase works fine but the thumbnail images are not displayed.

```
<ul class="ad-thumb-list">
            <?php
            //for($i=0;$i<$gallery_list_count;$i++)
            foreach($gallery_list as $key => $value)
            {
                $id = $value['id'];
                $title = $value['title'];
                $description = $value['description'];
                $image = $value['image'];
                $img = "../gallery_image/".$id."/".$image ;
                $thumb_filename = splitfilename($image,'_th');
                $thumb_image = "../gallery_image/".$id."/".$thumb_filename;

                echo '<li><a href="'.$img.'" ><img src="'.$thumb_image.'" title="'.$title.'" /></a></li>';

            } ?>
          </ul>
```

This images are retrieved from a database. 
[image]
The lightbox gets displayed as a small dot.
Now, I want the images to be displayed properly as they where in PHP 5.2. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Do some debugging – enable sensible error_reporting, and look into the generated HTML source to see if there are any error messages there.

Comment: @CBroe it is css issue...i guess html generated is fine

Comment: Don’t “guess”, _check!_ And if this was a CSS issue, then what would it have to do with PHP?

Comment: @CBroe So what are you suggesting me...should I start with HTML

Comment: I already gave you a suggestion.

Comment: The issue is not that your jQuery plugin and PHP 5.3 aren't friends and don't get along, since they never even know each other - as the plugin simply operates on the HTML (front-end) output by PHP (back-end).  CBroe's suggestion is the best way to go.  Begin with NOT initializing your plugin and compare the HTML code (line by line) generated by the two PHP versions.  If you're sure the HTML is the same, then echo out and compare the content, description, etc.. and ensure that everything matches up across versions.  If all else is equal (scripts, css...) then it's an issue with the HTML gen'd.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure, because you haven't shown us your entire code -- specifically, you haven't shown us what the `splitfilename()` does.

However, if `splitfilename()` lives up to its name and uses the PHP `split()` function, then your problem is obvious.

PHP's `split()` function was deprecated as of PHP 5.3. Using it in PHP 5.3 will cause a warning message to be output.

Since you're using PHP to display an image file, you won't see that warning message, but it will make your image file invalid, even if the rest of it is output correctly.

The solution is to switch your code to use the `explode()` function instead.

You should also check whether you're using any of the other features that were deprecated in PHP 5.3, because they will give you the same issues, so you will need to fix them.

Additionally, those features that were deprecated in 5.3 are removed entirely in PHP 5.4, so you should consider it an urgent fix to be done before you find yourself needing to upgrade again.

Finally, you should consider checking also for features that are deprecated in 5.4 and 5.5. There are some fairly major features in that list, and if you want to avoid the same problems in the future it's good to know about them and start re-working your code to avoid them.